# The process of cutting and shaping sheet metal so that air can pass through? like sides of a 1968 Corvette Stingray

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

Perhaps more technical or industry related, but what is the English word that describes the process of cutting and shaping sheet metal so it breathes yet aerodynamic and weather resistant. Kind of like the gills on the sides of a 1968 Corvette Stingray?

For some reason thinking Rivet or Velour.. but that does not appear to be it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. found it louver press.

https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=S4R1Q3ZL&id=B933F49F9EAE463C0458C9853D21A05DC5361C26&thid=OIP.S4R1Q3ZLJ4gDmdJis-WK1AHaHa&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mittlerbros.com%2fmedia%2fcatalog%2fproduct%2fcache%2f1%2fsmall_image%2f9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2fl%2fo%2flouver-press_1_copy.jpg&exph=1000&expw=1000&q=louver+machine&simid=608053589049150192&selectedIndex=0&ajaxhist=0

Comment: Thought you might have meant expanded metal sheet: https://www.metalsupermarkets.com/difference-between-perforated-metal-expanded-metal-and-wire-mesh/   Except 1968 corvette did not have that stuff. I've always called the louvers **gills** Don't know how widespread that usage is.